# How do I get the new SPL token-metadata interface to work with SPL token-2022's metadata-pointer extension?

Tags: metadata, token-2022

Just to confirm if I understood all the docs correctly. Basically to get them to work I have to:

- Have a metadata program that adheres to the [token-metadata interface](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token-metadata/interface). Critically, it needs to handle the `Emit` instruction with the specified discriminator `b"\xfa\xa6\xb4\xfa\r\x0c\xb8F"` and instruction args. This instruction must set the return data to the raw bytes of the token's [TokenMetadata struct](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/eeb1ca9601afb3675011063cc20d87fbb3b693aa/token-metadata/interface/src/state.rs#L25) in TLV format, or a subslice of it depending on the instruction args.
- Set the metadata_address to this metadata program when I [initialize](https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/latest/spl_token_2022/extension/metadata_pointer/instruction/struct.InitializeInstructionData.html) the mint with the metadata-pointer extension
- Now when wallets or dapps need to read the token metadata they call/index the `Emit` instruction and read the return data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your program to work with the metadata-pointer extension, there's no requirements at all! It's just a dumb pointer that can point anywhere.

The concept is that it points to a metadata *account*, and not a metadata *program*. For example, you could use a metaplex metadata account, which is totally different and has many more features than the simple SPL metadata interface.

And yes, the `Emit` instruction is probably the most important one. The flow goes:

- fetch the mint
- read the metadata pointer address
- fetch the account at that address
- simulate an `Emit` instruction pointing at the program that owns the metadata account and pass the metadata account too
- alternatively, if your metadata program adheres to the state in the metadata interface, the client can just read the bytes from your account, without needing to simulate a transaction

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I also just found out that spl-token-2022 itself implements the `token-metadata` interface by storing the metadata in the mint account itself using the [token-metadata extension](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/program-2022/src/extension/token_metadata), which means you probably don't have to implement a metadata program yourself.

Couple of points to take note of when using the `token-metadata` extension:

- The `metadata` account in the [token-metadata `Initialize` instruction](https://docs.rs/spl-token-metadata-interface/0.2.0/spl_token_metadata_interface/instruction/enum.TokenMetadataInstruction.html#variant.Initialize) must be set to the mint address
- The mint must have been initialized already with the `metadata-pointer` extension initialized with `metadata_address` pointing to itself
- When you create the system account to initialize, you must not allocate the additional space required for the metadata extension or it'll result in `InvalidAccountData` during mint initialization. The `token-metadata` extension initialization will `realloc()` the account to the appropriate size
- However, you must ensure that the mint account is rent-exempt for this new extended size.

In short, if you're going to create a token-2022 mint with the `metadata-pointer` and `token-metadata` extension programmatically, the instructions to execute would be:

1. create account with size = [`ExtensionType::try_calculate_account_len::<Mint>(&[ExtensionType::MetadataPointer])`](https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/latest/spl_token_2022/extension/enum.ExtensionType.html#method.try_calculate_account_len), but lamports = rent-exempt amount for (above result + [`token_metadata.tlv_size_of()`](https://docs.rs/spl-token-metadata-interface/0.2.0/spl_token_metadata_interface/state/struct.TokenMetadata.html#method.tlv_size_of)).
2. [Initialize metadata pointer extension](https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/latest/spl_token_2022/extension/metadata_pointer/instruction/fn.initialize.html)
3. [Initialize mint](https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/latest/spl_token_2022/instruction/fn.initialize_mint2.html)
4. [Initialize token metadata](https://docs.rs/spl-token-metadata-interface/0.2.0/spl_token_metadata_interface/instruction/fn.initialize.html)